# Image received by Kafka-console-consumer is processed correctly but by java program it is corrupt. How to solve this?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to send an image from one kafka-producer to another kafka-consumer. I have written a java program for the consumer and when the data (image converted to bytes) is received by kafka-console-consumer as (terminal command > imageName.jpg ) it is showing correctly in the image viewer but when I am trying to consume this image data by a java-consumer, the image viewer isn't able to open the image (as it is corrupt).

## Java Producer:

The Producer first converts the image to byte

```
public static byte[] getByte(File f) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    int read;
    while((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
        os.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    fis.close();
    os.close();
    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

Then the producer configurations are as follow

```
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, args[1]);
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
```

When I receive the data sent by this java producer, using CLI, the image is correctly shown. The command is

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server1 --topic topic-name > imageName.jpg
```

The thing is that I am not giving any other consumer configuration (such as for deserializing, etc.) other than those mentioned in the command above.

## Java Consumer:

I thought that I would simply save the producer's data value into a jpg file and it would work. I thought that because I didn't give any other configs in the CLI command as well. The Java Consumer is as follows

```
//String bootstrapServer = args[0];
String bootstrapServer = "[::1]:9092";
String group_ID = "myThirdApplication";
//String topic = args[1];
String topic = "second_topic";

// Create Consumer Properties
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
//properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, group_ID);
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, /*"none/earliest/latest"*/ "earliest");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, CooperativeStickyAssignor.class.getName());
```

I have tried both StringDeserializer which saves the data into a file but the file (which is supposed to be an image file) is corrupt and ByteArrayDeserializer seem to give an error.

This is how I am saving the file

```
String fileName = String.valueOf(record.timestamp()) + ".jpg";
File myFile = new File(fileName);
try {
    if(myFile.createNewFile()){
        log.info("File Created: " + myFile.getName());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info("An Error Occurred While Creating File!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
FileWriter data = null;
try {
    data = new FileWriter(fileName);
    log.info("FileWriter Created!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info("An Error Occurred While Creating FileWriter!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    data.write(Byte.valueOf(record.value()));
    log.info("Successfully Written Data!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info("An Error Occurred While Writing File!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    data.close();
    log.info("File Closed!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.info("An Error Occurred While Closing File!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I thought the problem lies in the deserialization. I tried to know the default deserialization that kafka-consumer use, but I found that there is no default setting for this.

### EDIT 1:

I am sharing a snippet of the file which is actually being received on the console vs in the java program:

**Console --**

```
lmd#-z syB(^7"��ix0p탮`Q*s7.K#���q(]P;'$+p k+kL׌N|QBjSA]KR1je?Q]#mU(Vj7s      ��<y02w- >s)lFsHͳyEE,5u\VK        6,a?2uþ"]Х',QALi緉@|yi.*(HQʳu2duWH,#͹f|eM5zx8xa%ŧXN}%UD ;rs$rF(pGA2xR9TJ.s3afcpT/1G;Ġ|`5Hux\��&`oτ^q܁R]2/[GP߳F5p){fiae?Ԩ!WKFJ,)Cr`;?gOW;= ȣ8dA)2]NLz(RwÁJqWKV~^!7̰WQ��0aըԻFT!C(ULR5ss_MxTQ\UCk&wFeyIQ<ij\@s ތO,m_iJV1YB.."Qc2"<5(hgGd0О       <oPLSCYcu3.;pڜ
ӼKLߺ>vbCdŚ<ꃶ邮k{BYML!3!*OTY(;3֦u(8ϦU&hlbk"xp5I}WdS>c1    vy{*    -c0k:rm^扖{mF-ц}nsj[߹J*>eg2&
@s       ;$xd[3h: [۪!FQ^gkmO1#SrQAx]wkEi&m}ـn!0$TV!'4x<~Uܰw?xcd<<\��_wu/r3˓k0v+<CPvf,\wش/?I^p䁰YzI6ür;:288ʯ2R-WxqUۺ4Fʼ\sF13|м1]EU{Cd$V?XmOЙ恪H7h5A'w0DN_IoPs0%eVc63[TcOVUMX<r]9q7rhFW&Y`Gm&(v+2ߨc+
.ￂX=Q;L y"^#jdvuw56)6_Еl^n
LTP"}eN55 ڟ5T+cA;GEqR#[fq/s2RΡdG Nf^e^,Bc)0]>eYs/q+cLNvL"=䇕<wlE^n.7qjj
;#딥ȓ͚2I*;Ps2¸o]ҥ兜xGԼCt]b(e~O\V4H9r\uxxjl5^._BGm    rg/zcj%PLD:T2?~{Tv%eG2=*   s6X2K.yG%v~æK㾸7;3Je@F])[0<omҡP)]`7
 @uD(8-%re+
lK!Jkx0@UJ[>3j#`4dRs.voH3Txiy̵IC{0[.ٔDFTflbeKe?@h~ӈg,7U!e5Q,̥C9$}GN6{o@ESoL%Y
<6V8+Ajpx9o|(602wPK4y*;3//
R˯Ńn{7ITybƯ!)��]4d"!@{C ]WUwO     KM[Ƨ٠}l35*c6IXA{zg/(I.\E8/h)LNSlEa˞Q퉠hwP&[Pb,;xf&בs]M~)+XCofNiIӁBmj548Q9њ>blNWBݏQ
2R=teḳ*TeJ%JnE%bg/jؙ c]:*x.
(qm
%L
pFdFR㙞wי/b;o!yo0L` 6<hY߬olqzw
"tUMi     Tm~ef[.֠KX2_Sr0c4ǽ@7N`rcot]*dk5+Pf/݈"Xܸn2XJ3GhL@eh0mWپrY9Ϭɵ]9   *'c\iL^DWcZjj0ż14��{͔U)XevJi}55BܸofX^݈8G^:*>|Ba?CbzMwW%}fkneO
j]R\D&)3VҶ1S=݂c^ĉ'!)ṯkd+kϙqg0-!S}(LAWZ/cm> tFTj2KC.rMbvYyOK;:C-t#Hʚ6~kWw눘qQ̢y`Qhk2jY cV^;0!IW
3~MQb 5d_!)L^=۩i!k48zhl^W+#\;vxCJL*)MB햃
ĥe^bbD:'H!r1ZTDo1QL        M1@BAFmϷb
ᅲ9,91,ąs%ˡⰎBHB(/UKgVaP/1Cz!NaS|e;K2d*#"}>"1P:9E._V@Ōwo%@ʗcw':au=fQ'61/U&}=h؎i;HDkQk!*p½
vB%+*:S0c+BYRѮgn,nZpJFdܽX"zyP]1%Vn%|L!ЯɊjMmԲ\+rL'SqZd5B%+r7u-f|
&)DbSYe9,b"��a؎ؕI%ŗ2@vNǘ!ygZU,
o^!\SIf2yh*э0c+↢0 Iw?
!"D[e"]3[Ar(>/̴؁HYK9&"(W3Jm\aa1Бu>\Z5HЗ)*_:_Igfp渎7jJ撺s9     rn]UMp]0,<lsy6sx'0]vS/љ5ؗ1S6ԾfbdIQʸGNERJHSH^  ]ہ̬j<y̌dA-Xaxkjĵ0��%Il,TJm4:M۲^ňݣqe͎VEe\xH1P&TYJ{-c0D]&pFXgf]#*,B27q4dάבHK^sӶnR/#PP|oS_.?x">!"Dۓ,-̦UMCtj-jR;COKOrf^C;;b.%+sDPs46       e~"6Uu,��ieX5Ţ=.l.W$XO⸆ݦLf_,v슈**YL|G}&mj`yB)is9L!eK[h"ZeY"{8Db&lM~)Z1W9EWPEVt$x\MZec/&rL߳+Lu~e6pQ5jܽlDlf gO>!7sL&0Gl%8b0IR;FR.zqCYc.ΝF3ɘ0c(o\]ao1R0B
@��&dtib",B6Ypk*DzoEb+SB.#f%J0
A9'(p6.?6cSU&ӮY:'MTL
H_EF΀(Eb19*T,#B%&F쭠V^Θ3&dFXvB!.%pAFM1\Lᇼ f0$_M\As      vwxq0!HbY!
```

**IntelliJ --**

```
???tC???v?xE?x?w)f??[O??J??I????\?`?*)??$R??tq,?* 5?H@x?_?Ka8/??l?^?? jo??0??V?x0?l??#a]?y&Sq?xc???t?S?P?M???/u??8G)
???v?o??0s0(_L??t?@??M???J???H  A#Xe???iy?S??_ ?<?1?Kp?????[?}?�_ _?W????3????????{??56?k???c???j?JZ???????3?'?_v? ???6p~???}????o??Z?Op<?t???9???:??�? i?rd/???[?? ??]pAPQsx?????q>]N!S#????2?(?jiW?}???;?c?C?xM^?V?YP?@F?k3?g?r?.mK??Ej3
[H???h
L??.]? t?sb~?1?m?@?q?5?vE?u??????\?.??g,Bd.U??@?,*]@!(??Q??????B?y??????Li????E??????p??X??k?????????+??    N?p???By?????p?7?zY? ??????EN?I??.???�8`F??aK? u?_??    ?x???   oRs??_(?{R?XE,?2U
)???*?^?qz{???1?x?6/???I<??JZ!???<??]?E6????f ???]p?)??&??,? ??)?w?"? ? m?h?*???2?+?Xx;??v??
h?Fb@?!?P^????%?Zo?p|u?b\?e^%-&eQ6?u???N?? ?<??x??#J????XZ?Gz?i? ???(?_D??~Z??O?\,?y$NU??R-?sx??+???u,&L???????&????%?Y? k???
?#?+??W?!??Q??????Z5?Eiec?H5??_@???4?7P??P?S??\?6-�8??.?"u? )v?mz,??    ??A?I???j?e?28-(XR*??(??~?U0i%?xz??t?v? 5??wj2,U??�3M??Y?@,=z?N_?h_EB7???E???????z?????X??????????????01?I?x??r?m?@?&<W??????a4?ly???!N?X???}?J?Z`???   ?????WG???r?Z??&Q?:?m??3*?"?2_?3BU???<?iL??#???#I
?q?0?L??%Z??yHj??E.??TH?>W?? f?? ???????_?Q?Y?Otn'?#?&?)??:`?-?SL???????U?-?????,Q?0{?f4q???Nm|F??#??=?y?8_??gj\u5n?/>??h??\??$}?
Oe?$sQT}\ ??P{??s????N??;?#P?m???B?PTZ? ????m???a?S??U*??./3??F?0???????gD??8^?UjSVv-S??)?"???k??IJF?b???q6R`1????{??`Z?W????????TR????:??????????CZ6??????[!qI?????e?A????\????C-???WdAnRN???v%p??j?+???F?*????p??[lZ=?@??K??
#at3?bK?5"6@? ???)+?
?Lg ??.k
???(?+-?O??Bo???V C?l!??xc?4??7<??*>V?S??
Zlv??oUJHl?p?1
??? io??k?QEyahR?O? ]??,&??+?V@??0?h????(0I?:~?h(Jy?X?M????6(?R#OiIv?a??#?l?k?%?E????Pai??O#j?X?y???.W??z?Y^s??-??b?$|?@?x?EO[wp???XK??????H?.Y???8?(??(Y?I?W4?0)?t/?1%?2??$??  ??????yQ??Ig?q@???^?s??a?/'?T?>a_}???jW5-qlZ?
?jK?Qls?}xE2??g?????o2???ji^?Yy?O??uLTZ:?P
?   i?5h??[0? ????{ ????N????
??H`??L??xZz!?P?^?7?$??.#,?Sg?O?(?Af?sgp?j??U?r???p???]/V??  J'?Q?? Y8??|Q?EZ??;?"=???
1?????BGe~?P*lr??D[
???5&]???|?Y?)??S}?rQ??O ?n??????D?a@???d7"Il'.?+k?J?j+??@j????L? ]%G??f8??4]P???W???8?<T#
```

I don't know how to define this but there is clearly a difference between what is being received on console vs on IntelliJ.

### EDIT 2:

I found the solution but this wasn't the exact problem. I found out that I was using the wrong KafkaConsumer. I was using

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

Whereas, I should have used

```
KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

I am thankful for everyone who has tried to solve this issue and I am sorry for my silly mistake.

Comment: You can try to convert your image to base64 and send it to kafka consumer, and then  see if it works

Comment: You mean image->base64->byteArraySerialization->byteArrayDeserialization->base64->image?

Comment: What is the error? ByteArrayDeserializer is trivial (it returns input provided without doing anything).

Comment: The error I am getting with ByteArrayDeserializer is
'java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.lang.String ([B and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at ConsumerOne.main(ConsumerOne.java:76)'

Comment: FWIW, Kafka, in general, shouldn't be used to send images. At least, not if they are several MB files... You can upload the image/file to a shared filesystem (S3 or NFS are common) between the consumers and producers, and send a file URI location **as a string** onto the topic, then have the consumer read the file remotely.

Comment: I am using compressed images. They are not more than 300 kb in size.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug in *ByteArrayDeserializer*.

You are doing a wrong conversion. Remember that `ConsumerRecord` is generic, and it is your responsibility use received key/value as correct types, that match the Deserializers provided.

In your code you are doing:

```
data.write(Byte.valueOf(record.value()));
```

what invokes `Byte.valueOf(String)`.

Extract the received record-value, you do not need convert it. To show it explicitly:

```
byte[] bytes = record.value() // you just get the bytes
data.write(bytes)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. I have tried to apply what you've written but IntelliJ is giving me an error in this and forcing the "bytes" to be a string type. I am editing the question for extra details.